# css background-image intelligent positioning

Tags: css

Okay so I wanna do something I thought would be quite simple but I can't seem to find how.

I have to divs (in fact a nav and a main) and css like this:

```
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: calc(100vh - 3em);
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 3em);
  margin-left: 300px;
  background: url('../images/background.jpg');
}

footer {
  height: 3em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I want for my background image is

- to be fixed (not moving
  while I scroll main)
- to always take the whole main section but not
  overflowing into the margin or acting as if the margin was a part of
  the main (for exemple when I try to center the image, it centers on
  the whole page, ignoring the margin)
- since the image will not always
  fit the main ratio w/h, i want it to either fill 100% width or height
  and then overflow on the other dimension, but...
- always be centerd

Is all this possible? I made a codepen: https://codepen.io/cypherfirelair/pen/yLYNMKY

EDIT: I found an even better way of combining horizontal and vertical center and an offset both at the left and bottom: background-position: calc(50% + 150px) calc(50% - 2.5em);

Comment: can you add html code , and the image plz

Comment: My html is really just <body><nav></nav><main></main><footer></footer></body>
And my image is 4608x3456px you can try https://s1.1zoom.me/big3/998/Spain_Scenery_Mountains_Forests_Cantabria_525299_4608x3456.jpg for example but i'd like the code to work with any picture if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the solution to your problem, i just changed these two elements :`background-size: calc(100vw - 300px) auto;` and `background-position: 300px;`  : https://codepen.io/Aypro18/pen/LYpVWMd

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: calc(100vh - 3em);
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 3em);
  width:calc(100vw - 300px);
  margin-left:300px;
  background: url('https://s1.1zoom.me/big3/998/Spain_Scenery_Mountains_Forests_Cantabria_525299_4608x3456.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: calc(100vw - 300px) auto;
  background-position: 300px;
}

footer {
  height: 3em;
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With these attributes, the picture is "centered" not taking the margin into account. The leftmost 300px of my main div are margin coverd by the nav div so the center of the picture should be 300px on the right but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: can you add the image to your question , i'll try to do an exemple for you

Comment: I made a codepen: https://codepen.io/cypherfirelair/pen/yLYNMKY

Comment: See how the image centers on the whole page, not the main div minus the left margin?

Comment: Oh yes I see! Although I changed the value to 150px instead of 300px otherwise it's too far on the right. Thank you very much :)

Comment: i added another update , cause i noticed that the image is not taking 100% of main width

Comment: Oops sorry it wasn't on purpose!